# Unity Gitignore not ignoring binary files

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, repository

I have a problem with the **.gitignore file** in my Multiplayer Unity game project (consists of a game server and a client project in a single repository). The .gitignore file ignores most of the files, but not the binary files from the library artifacts.
[Image of binary files showing in Github Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7TQH.jpg).

I know the .gitignore file works because if I remove it there is 30000 changed files and 8000 without removing it.

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
[Ll]ogs/
[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Asset meta data should only be ignored when the corresponding asset is also ignored
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

[Image of the repository folder with the 2 projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Flr8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

hehe i think your answer is on the first line of the `.gitignore`

**This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory**

All of those ignore paths without a preceeding `/` are only relative to the location of the `.gitignore`. It works like so:

Will ignore:

- `./Build/myBinary`

Will not ignore:

- `./project1/Build/myBinary`
- `./project2/Build/myBinary`

Simplest solution is to duplicate your .gitignore and place one of each at the root of each **project directory**, not the repo directory.

Your directory should look like this:

- myRepo

  - project1

    - .gitignore
    - Assets
    - ...
  - project2

    - .gitignore
    - Assets
    - ...

As mentioned, if files in these directories have already been committed they will need to be removed manually.

Comment: I have duplicated the gitignore file to the projects folder but I still have the files showing up in the git status

Comment: gitignore only works for files that are not already tracked. try this: 1. remove the files (with the original gitignore in place), 2. `git add . && git commit`, 3. put the duplicated gitignores in the right place, 4. `git status`

Comment: By remove the files is it like deleting the library folder or what? (sorry i'm new to using repositories)

Comment: yes thats right, maybe make a backup first :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The library files are now ignored as intended.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, assuming there are only binaries in this folders, try and delete them (from the Git index only, not from your disk), and check immediately (no commit needed) if your `.gitignore` applies.

```
cd /path/to/repo
git rm -r --cached path/to/folder/with/binaries/ # note the trailing slash

git check-ignore -v path/to/folder/with/binaries/aBinary # must be a file
```

If the last command does not return anything, then no `.gitignore` rule applies.

Comment: The last command returned a .gitignore:5:[Ll]ibrary/ but the files still show up on the github desktop.

Comment: @JaydenKusuma Are they still shown if you do a `git status`? (assuming you did delete the folder content from the index)

Comment: They still show on git status. I tried doing the git rm -r --cached as suggested above but it returned a 'fatal: pathspec 'library' didn't matched any files'

Comment: @JaydenKusuma Are you in a folder where you see the subfolder `library`? (with the git case, since it could be case sensitive).

Comment: Yes I have the folder library inside my unity project and already navigated there

Comment: @JaydenKusuma Can you share a screenshot (by editing your question) where: 1/ you do a `git check-ignore -v -- library/aFile` 2/ `git status` *still* does show `library/aFile`?